# can getters be used in equals and hashcode?

Tags: java

I have below code which overrides equals() and hashcode() methods.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj)
 {
   if (obj == null)
     return false;
   if (!(obj instanceof Name))
     return false;
   Name name = (Name) obj;
   return this.name.equals(name.name);
 }

 public int hashCode()
 {
   return name.hashCode();
 }
```

here can i replace below 2 lines:

```
return this.name.equals(name.name);
return name.hashCode();
```

with

```
return this.getName().equals(name.getName());
return getName().hashCode();
```

i mean instead of using properties can i directly use getters inside equals and hashcode methods?

Thanks!

Comment: yes, There isn't any problem.

Comment: yes. You just can't use setters or fields which can be modified when the object is in a collection.

Comment: BTW: `!(null instanceof Name)` is always true so the first check is redundant.

Comment: Yes. I had an issue when trying to compare two (hibernate proxied) entity objects. Only the equals method implementation with getters works perfectly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but why would you? Option A: the compiler inlines that, so you end up with a reference to the field anyway. Option B: The compiler does not inline the call, i.e. you've introduced one extra method call.

There are also implications for legibility- if the `name` field is directly accessible within the class, why not refer to it directly? I find this easier to read, but some people find it inconsistent.

Comment: As a small note. If you use Mokito, and mock one of the getters that are used in equals and your equals method is final you will go to infinite loop hell. Mokito uses equals internally to mock your fields. Normally it overwrites you equals, but if it's marked as final you get StackoverflowError

Answer (score 4):

**Yes** sure you could use this,

`hashcode()` and `equals()` are field methods, They can access private members directly, but what if there is some logic wrapped in accessor method, so it is always safe to access fields using accessor methods

Comment: In the case of entities if a getter isn't returning the exact field I will introduce a difference in the unicity handled in the DB and that handled in memory, so in the case of entities I believe it is dangerous to use getters. So use the hash and equals generators with care !

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I strongly recommend using getters in `equals() & hashCode()` implementation. And to the best of my knowledge, this will not harm you in any manner.

The implementation of `equals()` without getters will fail to give you the correct result when you compare two proxied objects.

*Eg:* If you try comparing two proxied objects returned by your underlying hibernate dao, you'll never receive *true* from your `equals()` method, even though they're same objects.

**Update**

> Use getter methods instead of direct access. This is because the
>   object instance passed as other may be a proxy object, not the actual
>   instance. To initialize this proxy, you need to access it with a
>   getter method.

Check [this](http://www.ideyatech.com/effective-java-equals-and-hashcode/) for more information.

Comment: I know this is old quesion to answer, but I am sure this will help some one working with proxies.

Comment: _"This is an excerpt from Effective Java."_ No, it is not. _Effective Java_ does not mention using getters inside `equals()` at all; in fact, it favors direct access. What you quoted is just advice form the author of the blog post you linked. Good advice nonetheless, but not an excerpt from EJ.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, why would you not be able to?

In future, with things like this, I recommend you just give it a try and see.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. Why not? What's your doubts?

Answer (score 0):

No.

Fields used in `hashCode()` should be `final` value types. If they aren't, the hash of the instance can change after it has been added to a map or set which will lead to runtime errors like `Map` not being able to find an instance that you just put into it.

Since `equals()` must behave the same as `hashCode()`, this requirement leaks into `equals()` as well. Since the field is `final`, subclasses should not overwrite the getter, so they should be `final` as well.

When the getter is `final`, there is no point to use it in `equals()`/`hashCode()`: It's more characters to type, more code to read, makes compilation slower (the compiler must consider to inline this), might make execution slower.

For more information about the many pitfalls of equals()/hashCode(), see the excellent [EqualsVerifier](https://jqno.nl/equalsverifier/manual/).